# Is there a JavaBlackBelt equivalent for .Net?

Tags: .net

I used to use JavaBlackBelt a lot when I was first learning java, I have now switched to .Net and I was wondering if there was an equivalent site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing like JavaBlackBelt that is smartly motivating developers to enhance their skills. You have to pay Microsoft for any test.

Answer (score 1):

I found [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com) helped me a lot when I started out 7 years back. It was a lot less overcrowded then, but it remains an excellent resource for Windows and .NET programmers.

Comment: I haven't been back to the site in quite a long time... I use to be very active on the forums... that brings back memories.

Answer (score 1):

Actually JavaBlackBelt has some stuff (beta exams) for c#. I hope many more to come

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend CodeBetter.com its not the same but very insightful.

Comment: You need to take a lot of the content on there with a pinch of salt though. There are some fanatical One True Way bloggers on there...

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Developer Network ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com)) has a section on [training](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb188199.aspx).  I realize that it's not an open community, but since you're new to .NET I thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 0):

I like [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com)